# Is this true regarding this intersection

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Given that $\exists \ O, O'$ two open sets in $\mathbb{R}^d \ s.t. O \supset A, O' \supset A^c$ where none are empty.

I am trying to write $O \cap O'$ in terms of $O \setminus A$ and $O' \setminus A^c$. Is it true in this case that

1. $ O \ \cap \ O' \subset (O \setminus A) \cap (O' \setminus A^c)   $

Or

2. $ O \ \cap \ O' \subset (O \setminus A) \cup (O' \setminus A^c)   $

Comment: @noam.szyfer I am trying to write $O \cap O'$ in terms of $O \setminus A$ and $O' \setminus A^c$. Maybe I was wrong to use the intersection. But using a diagram, the intersection made more sense.

Answer (score 0):

While I am not sure about the second option, the first option seems false by counterexample:
Suppose $A \subset O$, and $O'=\mathbb{R}^d$. Clearly, $A^c \subset \mathbb{R}^d$, so our conditions on the sets hold.

However, $O \setminus A$ is smaller than $O$, but the intersection between $O$ and $\mathbb{R}^d$ should equal $O$.

Answer (score 0):

If we develop the RHS of the first statement:
\begin{align*}
 (O\backslash A) \cap (O^{\prime}\backslash A^c )&= (O\cap A^c) \cap (O^{\prime}\cap (A^c)^c) \\
&=O\cap A^c \cap O^{\prime}\cap A \\
&=O\cap O^{\prime} \cap A^c \cap A \\
&=\emptyset
\end{align*}
So unless $O\cap O^{\prime}=\emptyset$, the first statement is false. And if we suppose that: $O\cap O^{\prime}=\emptyset$, then we can prove that we have $O=A$ and $O^{\prime}=A^c$

Here is a proof of the second one:
\begin{align*}
O\cap O^{\prime}&=O\cap O^{\prime} \cap \mathbb{R}^d\\
&=O\cap O^{\prime} \cap (A^c \cup A) \\
&=(O\cap O^{\prime} \cap A^c) \cup (O\cap O^{\prime} \cap A)\\
&=(O\cap O^{\prime} \cap A^c) \cup (O\cap O^{\prime} \cap A)\\
&=(O \cap O^{\prime} \cap A^c) \cup (O^{\prime} \cap O \cap A)
\end{align*}

Since $A^c \subset O^{\prime}$ and $A \subset O$ then $ O^{\prime} \cap A^c=A^c$ and $O \cap A=A$

So, we get:
\begin{align*}
O\cap O^{\prime}&=(O \cap  A^c) \cup (O^{\prime} \cap A)\\
&=O\backslash A \cup O^{\prime} \backslash A^c
\end{align*}